# Install software in ISO files

Tags: windows, windows-8, iso-image, windows-installation

I have just downloaded an ISO of the Windows 8 Operating System onto my PC that is currently running Windows 7. Instead of burning a DVD, how can I install Windows 8 directly? Also, it is very important that all of my documents are not destroyed. Will this keep all my documents?

Comment: The best way not to use the DVD would be to use the upgrade assistance tool.  It will offer you to "install" Windows 8 without burning or creating a USB key.  You can get around having to actually purchase Windows 8 by usng the installer that is sent to you when you purchase it through the tool.  Since you don't have the installer already just use the DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is very important that all of my documents are not destroyed.

In that case: Step 1 in to make a backup of all of your documents.

Seriously. If you are worried about that, make and test a backup. And store it somewhere else. Even if the upgrade goes well you want it for the day something goes wrong.

Having said that: If you want to upgrade from Win 7 (normal 64 bit version) to windows 8 (normal 64 bit version) then that *should* work without problems.

*Should*.

If you try to change between 32 bit and 64 bit versions then you will need a clean installation.

Comment: What is the best way to backup everything? I have general stuff in the MyDocuments directory, but what about programs, and the data that they have generated?

Comment: It depends on how you organised your data. The easiest way is to go to you start menu and type `backup `. That should find *backup and restore*. That allows you to make a full system backup, ensuring that you have everything.  You can also make sure you select only your documents, which will be much smaller and faster, but you need to make sure that you select everything you want to keep. Therefor I recommend one full backup of the current windows 7 setup. Then install windows 8 and fine tune.

Comment: As a side advantage that also allows you to revert to the old windows 7 installation in case you do not like windows 8. (Opinions on win8 are rather mixed, but having the option to revert is never a bad idea).